# Find a vector v⃗ parallel to the intersection of the planes 2x+y+5z=3 and 4x+2y+2z=7.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm not sure what the first step is here. Could anyone explain how to do this problem even in just step by step wording? You dont have to figure out the answer im just not sure what the steps are here. thank you

Comment: A very similar problem can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726835/find-a-vector-parallel-to-the-line-of-intersection-of-the-two-given-planes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a vector parallel to the line of intersection of the two given planes.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726835/find-a-vector-parallel-to-the-line-of-intersection-of-the-two-given-planes)

Answer (score 0):

Since, the line of intersection of the planes lie in both the planes so it is perpendicular to normals of both the planes. So, just take cross product of $(2i+j+5k)$ and $(4i+2j+2k)$